# Twilio fails to play long audios in realtime application

Tags: flask, twilio, twilio-api, openai-api, twilio-twiml

I'm attempting to create a phone chatbot that I can speak with when calling a number by using ChatGPT, Whisper, OpenAI's TTS, and Twilio. The following program uses Flask and ngrok to connect to Twilio, and it works fine... until OpenAI's TTS generates a long audio. For some reason, Twilio encounters an error whenever the chatbot attempts to speak a few seconds longer than usual. There's no error in my local Terminal (Twilio simply says during the call "Sorry, an application error has occurred” and logs “error 11200 HTTP retrieval failure” or “error 11205 HTTP connection failure” in the Twilio console.)

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, url_for
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse
from twilio.rest import Client
from openai import OpenAI

app = Flask(__name__)

# OpenAI API setup
openai = OpenAI(api_key="redacted")

# Twilio setup
account_sid = "redacted"
auth_token = "redacted"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

# Chat history
chat_history = {}

@app.route("/twiliowebhook", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
    from_number = request.values.get('From')
    if from_number not in chat_history:
        chat_history[from_number] = []

    resp = VoiceResponse()
    resp.record(action='/twiliorecord', transcribe=False, max_length = 60)

    return str(resp)

@app.route("/twiliorecord", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def record():
    recording_url = request.values.get('RecordingUrl')
    recording_sid = request.values.get('RecordingSid')
    from_user = request.values.get('From')

    try:    
        # Get the wav file from Twilio
        r = requests.get(f"{recording_url}.wav", auth=(account_sid, auth_token))
        audio_path = f"/Users/user/Downloads/{recording_sid}.wav"
        with open(audio_path, "wb+") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    
        # Transcribe audio using OpenAI
        with open(audio_path, "rb") as f:
            transcript = openai.audio.transcriptions.create(
                model="whisper-1",
                file=f
            )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during audio retrieval or transcription: {e}")
        return str(VoiceResponse().say("An error occurred. Please try again."))

    try:
        user_speech = transcript.text.strip()
        print(from_user, "says:", user_speech)
    
        # ChatGPT interaction
        message_buffer = [
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": "You are a helpful AI assistant."
            },
        ]
        chat_history[from_user].append(user_speech)
        for message in chat_history[from_user]:
            role = "user" if chat_history[from_user].index(message) % 2 == 0 else "assistant"
            message_buffer.append({
                "role": role,
                "content": message
            })

        chatgpt_response = openai.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=message_buffer,
            max_tokens=256
        ).choices[0].message.content.strip()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during ChatGPT interaction: {e}")
        return str(VoiceResponse().say("An error occurred while generating a response. Please try again."))

    try:    
        response = openai.audio.speech.create(
            model="tts-1",
            voice="alloy",
            input=chatgpt_response,
        )

        response.stream_to_file(f"/Users/user/Downloads/response_{recording_sid}.wav")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during TTS audio generation: {e}")
        return str(VoiceResponse().say("An error occurred in audio generation. Please try again."))

    resp = VoiceResponse()
    
    audio_url = "https://849c-2603-7000-3f00-19e-2cdf-50a7-29b4-51b.ngrok-free.app" + url_for('audio_file', filename=f"response_{recording_sid}.wav")
        
    resp.play(audio_url)
    
    resp.record(action='/twiliorecord', transcribe=False, play_beep=False, max_length = 60)
    
    chat_history[from_user].append(chatgpt_response)
    
    return str(resp)

@app.route('/audio/<filename>')
def audio_file(filename):
    return send_file(f"/Users/user/Downloads/{filename}", mimetype='audio/mpeg')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

I have no idea why the code works for short responses but not for longer ones. I confirmed this is in fact the issue because if I change ChatGPT’s system prompt to “you always respond one word responses,” the error never happens, but if I set it to “you always give unnecessarily long responses,” it almost never works. Also, I noticed that some of the responses that failed attempted to play a ~45 seconds long audio, whereas the ones that succeeded were shorter than 35 seconds.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Do you mean you don’t see an error in the console of your app or the [Twilio Console](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/debugging-tools)? The later one should give you a detailed error message. Please add that one to your question.

Comment: There’s no error in the local console of my app, but the Twilio Console shows “error 11200” or “error 11205” (sometimes one, sometimes the other; I couldn’t identify any pattern). My theory is that when the audio is long, Twilio tries accessing it with play() before it’s done being hosted, so when it tries accessing the audio url it fails. However, I was unable to confirm that hypothesis and have no idea how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense as [Error 11205](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11205) states and HTTP connection failure.